# SQL Server's container not running through Docker Desktop

Tags: docker

SQL Server's container is not running. When I am trying to run then it is automatically stop. I am using these command step by step:

1. Pull and run the SQL Server 2022 Image

   ```
   docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
   ```
2. Create Container:-

   ```
   docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Brij@1982" -p 1440:1433 --name mysqlserver -h mysqlserver -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
   ```
3. All other containers are running fine, but the SQL Server container is not running. Any idea why?

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baR9G.png)

Comment: The container has exit code 1 `Exited(1)` that means it errored and stopped. Check the logs of the container for start.